# Is there any method : text to table with R?

Tags: r, regex

I have a strings which have some pattern.

for example

```
>oc
[1]"for financial company payment manufacturer company payment distributor people payment other payment total payment 1 month payment 10 20 30 40 100 2 month payment 8 14 15 30 67 1 year payment 5 9 11 15 40"
```

raw material is table and there is some disturbing things, I decide to extract text from table and organize, clean them with code then reshape table form.

The raw material table looks like this

```
     for financial company payment | manufacturer company payment | distributor people payment | other..
1 m..|            10                              20                             30                 ...
2 m..|            8                               14                             15                 ...
1 y..|            5                               9                              11                ...
```

I appreciate any method so please, leave any comment for it. It would be great help to me.
Also what I tried to do is first, use extract_text function (in tabilizer library)
and second I use regular expression to make strings tidy
finally I use scan function.

Again, any method is okay. please leave any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution--anything but elegant but working:

Your data:

```
oc <- "for financial company payment manufacturer company payment distributor people payment other payment total payment 1 month payment 10 20 30 40 100 2 month payment 8 14 15 30 67 1 year payment 5 9 11 15 40"
```

First, split the string at `payment`:

```
oc <- strsplit(oc, " payment ")
```

Prepare a matrix to fill in the data:

```
mt <- matrix(NA, ncol = 5, nrow = 3)
```

Grab the relevant elements from `oc` as column names:

```
colnames(mt) <- oc[[1]][1:5]
```

Define the rownames:

```
rownames(mt) <- c("1 month", "2 month", "1 year")
```

Grab the numbers from `oc`:

```
numbers <- ocx[[1]][7:9]
```

Clean `numbers`:

```
numbers <- gsub("( 2 month| 1 year)", "", numbers)
```

Now break`numbers` into individual numbers using `str_extract_all` from the package `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
numbers <- str_extract_all(numbers, "\\d+")
```

Iterate over the rows in `mt` to fill in the numbers from `numbers`:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(mt)){
  mt[i,] <- numbers[[i]]
}
```

Finally redefine `mt` as a dataframe:

```
mt <- as.data.frame(mt)
```

Et voilá, the result:

```
mt
        for financial company manufacturer company distributor people other total
1 month                    10                   20                 30    40   100
2 month                     8                   14                 15    30    67
1 year                      5                    9                 11    15    40
```